# Sanders says he has no plans to quit before the final primary votes have been cast in June

Tags: united-states, primaries, bernie-sanders, democratic-primary, democratic-party

Sanders says he has no plans to quit before the final primary votes have been cast in June.
 I want to know if there is statistics that shows his popularity diagram in the past year to see if it is increasing or decreasing?
I wonder if there is a hope for him to be Democratic candidate?

Comment: This is a very confusing question. Do you want to know his approval numbers, his general election numbers vs. Trump, his primary numbers vs HIllary or some other, less common "popularity diagram"?

Comment: @The Pompitous of Love I want to know if he gets more popular day by day, or less popular? can he beat HIllary ?

Comment: He was getting more popular but has been declining for about a month.  See the third link in my answer.  And the real problems are that most of the voting has already happened and that superdelegates aren't bound by voting.

Comment: There's also an issue in that popularity doesn't necessarily translate into winning in the case of the DNC candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Bernie Sanders has roughly two-thirds of Hillary Clinton's vote share.  The majority of states have already voted.

Source:  http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/democratic_vote_count.html

While California is the largest state, it is unclear that Sanders will win it.  Clinton is still up in California.

Source:  http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/ca/california_democratic_presidential_primary-5321.html

And Clinton is still up in nationwide polling, although that's closer than it was.

Source:  http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/us/2016_democratic_presidential_nomination-3824.html

Sanders needs roughly 65% of the remaining bound delegates to catch up to Clinton in bound delegates.  Even in states that he wins, he normally doesn't do that well.  There are some exceptions (e.g. Washington), but he normally wins smaller.  And he doesn't always win, which means that he is falling further and further behind.

Source:  http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/democratic_delegate_count.html

The race for bound delegates overstates Sanders case.  He needs to win a majority of all the delegates.  Even if he wins the bound delegates (and it seems unlikely that he will), he still has to overcome his deficit with superdelegates.  And they have the easy answer that they are voting for the person winning the popular vote.  It's Sanders who is asking the superdelegates to vote based on criteria other than the national popular vote.

Source:  http://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/democratic_vote_count.html

Is it still possible for Sanders to win?  Barely.  Likely?  No.  His popularity may have improved since the beginning, but he continues to underperform where he needs to be.  It's true that if he had been winning in February the way that he did in April, he'd be competitive if not winning.  But he wasn't.  So he has a large deficit to overcome.

Unless Hillary is indicted, it is very unlikely that Sanders will be the nominee.  Even if she is, it's not guaranteed that he will be.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a diagram you're looking for, the Huntington Post tracks polls, and they render them in a pretty decent-looking graph.

http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/2016-national-democratic-primary

They also have polls broken down by state and also polls for the republican races.